# Matplotlib: Plot movements in 3D

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a solver that solves a system of equations in 3 variables. Each iteration, it has a new guess on all three variables. The guesses over iterations look like this:

```
array([[ 0.86063431,  0.07119279,  1.70377142],
       [ 0.86391084,  0.07014899,  1.72184785],
       [ 0.86332177,  0.069444  ,  1.71182579],
       [ 0.86192988,  0.06913941,  1.69818289],
       [ 0.86166436,  0.06916367,  1.69527615]])
```

(Here for 5 iterations). I would like to plot these using matplotlib. I was thinking about having a dot for each of these coordinates, and have a line connecting them to show the order of coordinates.

Is this a good way of visualizing this? How would I do that using `matplotlib`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plot this as a 3D trajectory with matplotlib:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

points = np.array([[ 0.86063431,  0.07119279,  1.70377142],
                       [ 0.86391084,  0.07014899,  1.72184785],
                       [ 0.86332177,  0.069444  ,  1.71182579],
                       [ 0.86192988,  0.06913941,  1.69818289],
                       [ 0.86166436,  0.06916367,  1.69527615]]).T
    
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')
ax.plot(points[0], points[1], points[2], marker = 'x')
ax.scatter(*points.T[0], color = 'red')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Is there any way to show the direction? Whenever I highlight one of the points (for example, using `marker ='x'`, matplotlib won't connect him to the other points with a line anymore.

Comment: One way to that is to add a line like this (showing the first point in the trajectory): `ax.scatter(*points.T[0])` (possibly changing the marker properties to make it stand out from the others)

Comment: I edited the code so that the point becomes visible. It's just a matter of  what the markers look like. The order in which they are plotted is not always obvious, and it can be changed with the zorder command. However, in 3D it's not obvious how that works...  If this answers your question, please accept the answer